# Toastr notifications not rendering in Rails web app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, toastr

I'm beginning with Rails and I want to display error messages in my webapplication with Toastr but it doesn't render. I probably missed something or the tutorial that I am following is deprecated since Rails 6 and Webpacker)

## Gemfile :

```
#Toastr
gem 'toastr-rails', '~> 1.0'
```

## app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require toastr
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

import toastr from 'toastr';

toastr.options = {
    "positionClass":"toast-bottom-right"
}

global.toastr = toastr;
```

## app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "toastr";
@import 'toastr/build/toastr.min';
@import "toastr/toastr";
```

I can see the error messages in my logs (Connexion OK, new model created, etc..) but the toast is not rendering in my web page and the console contains this error message :

> (index):49 Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
> at (index):49

Comment: Does your project using webpacker or not? As I can see the code above is it's may, but I'm not sure

Comment: @NinhLe How can I be sure?

Comment: Check if your `Gemfile` contain  `webpacker` and in your project contain nodemodule?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation right now. Did you manage to resolve it? Toastr works fine for me on some pages but not on others. On the pages where the flash message is not displayed, it displays the same error as above.